# CMake - link with both static and dynamic libraries

Tags: c, cmake, arm, glibc

I have a `CMake` project that should run on very old `ARM` system. Since the system has different `libc` version then the toolchain one the only option is to link with `libc` statically.

The problem is that besides the `libc` the application should be linked with another dynamic library.
The CMakeFiles.txt looks like the following:

```
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC -static-libstdc++)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC -static-libgcc)

add_subdirectory(my_dynamic_library)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE my_dynamic_library)
```

But it looks that `libc` doesn't linked dynamically but as shared library:

```
readelf -d my_app

Dynamic section at offset 0x34668 contains 29 entries:
  Tag        Type                         Name/Value
 0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [my_dynamic_library.so]
 0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libm.so.6]
 0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libpthread.so.0]
 0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libc.so.6]
```

While running on the target system I get error:

```
./my_app: /lib/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.17' not found (required by ./my_app)
```

I have no clue why this is happening but for some reason gcc linked my apps with wrong libc versions:

```
objdump -T ./my_app| grep 2.17
000103a8      DF *UND*  00000000  GLIBC_2.17  clock_gettime
```

I've read a lot of similar posts and I see that I have to add

```
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC -static)
```

But that cause to another error:

```
../arm-none-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld: attempted static link of dynamic object my_dynamic_library.so
```

So I have no idea how to compile all that together.

Comment: > But it looks that libc doesn't linked dynamically but as shared library

Okay, shared object is a synonym to "dynamic library".

Answer (score 1):

Well, after a long search, I found a solution. Adding the following line:

```
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC rt)
```

solves the issue. No `-static` option needed.

and yes, I have no idea why it works.